# Add another module

Tags: 7, entities

I'm using the [Add another](http://drupal.org/project/addanother) module to insert multiple items for one field.

How can I remove the items I added with the module?

Comment: I have never used the module. But by its description it sounds like it adds new _nodes_, not new _field data_?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This discussion](http://drupal.org/node/1038316) resulted in the [Unlimited Field Remove](http://websmiths.co/blog/drupal-7-unlimited-fields-remove-button) module, which works great for Drupal 7 and may be going into the 8.x core.